# CRUD operation's on multiple google calender's (multiple clients calender)

Tags: jakarta-ee, google-calendar-api

I have to add/modify/delete/ event's (Patient Appointment) of  my client's  calendar(google calendar) from my web app. is it possible to do that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible

> Google provides a CalDAV interface that you can use to view and manage calendars using the CalDAV protocol.

(from [Google's CalDAV API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide))